# how to copy a disc with audio_ts and video_ts

Tags: dvd, file-transfer

How do I copy it? I can only see those two folders when I try to see the contents of the dvd.
And inside those folders I see a .vob file. Do I need to have a dvd ripping software to do the job for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or (if not copy protected) you can copy those files into your pc, players like vlc play for you, if you open like disc and browse those catalogs (In Media->Advanced Open File..).
Or you can get movie by ripping it with [dvd shrink](http://www.google.lt/search?q=dvd+shrink).

Comment: +1 for dvd shrink. Very good tool. It's a shame there's no ongoing development anymore, though.

Answer (score 2):

If the DVD is not copy protected, then you can copy it with any burning software with the copy command, or make an image file if you want to store it on your HD.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **HandBrake The open source video transcoder** at the moment. 
https://handbrake.fr/

For beginner use of Handbrake to copy DVD video_ts files to your hard drive, I recommend for example this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_dw0NTVZiQ